# Logback not inherting from root logger - Play framework

Tags: java, logging, playframework, logback

```
<logger name="services.EventInfoServiceImpl" level="INFO" />
<logger name="dao.EventInfoDaoImpl" />
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>

private static final Logger.ALogger logger = Logger
        .of(EventInfoDaoImpl.class);
```

Dao is not inherting from the root logger.I tried both INFO and DEBUG in root logger.Only if I specify a level explicitly in the dao logger,it is logging.

I have commented out the logger portion of application.conf.I have other dependent projects inside which has application.conf for the information.

Please point me in the right direction.

**Related question:** If I have got many application.conf through various dependent projects,which application.conf's values will be considered?

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed that the level of root logger is taken from some `application.conf` of dependent projects by doing the following :

```
<logger name="application" level="ERROR" />
```

and

```
Logger.info("### Checking logger.application value");
```

The configuration level for application logger starts only from ERROR.But Logger.info is getting logged which means some `application.conf` has INFO/DEBUG level which overrides the level given in the XML file.

The following quote is from play document:

> Note: Log level configuration in application.conf will also override
>   custom configuration. It is best to remove these properties when using
>   a Logback configuration file to avoid confusion.

So removing those properties from the main application's `application.conf` is not enough.Sub projects or plugins have to be checked as well.

Comment: still the related question remains open.